# Split tables to handle 100 inserts/second?

Tags: sql-server, performance, io

We will have a MS SQL Server database with 100 reads per second, 2,400 inserts evenly spread over one hour, and 14,400 updates evenly spread over one hour. Per month the environment could grow with 1,7M rows. The # of columns is under 20.

We are a container terminal with 60 cranes that are each handling 1 container at a given moment. Attributes of these tables are a/o : crane_ID (3 char), container_ID (11 char), container_unique_number (double), container_status (1 char), and a bunch of other details.

At any given moment, max 60 records (one crane handles one container) will be "active"; the rest is historic data.

Updates on active records will be done reading using 3 columns with one field (container_unique_number) being unique. The 100 I/Os (all different processes from various clients) are scans for all records that are active or for a specific container_id that is active. 
Half of the process is basically dedicated to one specific crane.

The design question that we are facing is :

- if we build one common table that holds all records for all cranes, with 100 queries (of distinct processes) on active records per second, will we have a performance issue?
- or should we build a dedicated (yet identical) table per crane and dedicate processes to specific tables eg the processes associated with crane 1 only read table CRANE1_blablabla?
- if we do build one common table, should we move "completed" records out to an archive table? What would the max nr of completed records be that you would allow to sit in this "active" table before you archive it?

Thanks,
  Simon

Comment: In general, a spindle drive or entry-level RAID *cannot* handle 100 *commits* per second (a 7.2K RPM should get about 30, a 15K up to about 60, depending on other factors). Commits are expensive, inserts/updates/"operations" are *very cheap* in comparison to the actual sync -- the price of [true] ACID support. This will vary some by database and ability to fine tune (or disable) sync'ing to non-volatile storage, which might ever-so-slightly increase the change of data-loss in extreme situations.

Comment: for `and a bunch of other details.` is that details related directly to the container move (does it change when the container moves) or is it things that should be in a `containers` table (such as the final destination of the container)?

Answer (score 3):

One table. This is a LOT more about the hardware than anything. Put in a SSD for logs and data and you are more than fine.

Splitting to multiple tables woudl get you fird in most companies, and that is despite the "supposed" performance gain. With good reason.

100 operations per second you can do on desktop hardware these days.

Comment: Hopefully not just a *single* SSD though ;-) They are darn fast (*so incredibly* much better at IOPS than spindle), but are also prone to suddenly ceasing to work; not even a "death tick" first :-( Standard redundancy/backups are still in full effect. +1

Comment: Yes. I did not go into this deliberatly, but the are freaking fast comapred to discs. Factor of 100 ;) Or more.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that even with splitting it into 60 different tables, you're going to get considerable worse performance as you'll fragment the data all over a spindle drive. Even when splitting into 60 different tables you're still committing 100 times per second, just now it's over 60 different locations on the disk instead of at the same location.

Comment: Plus all the other ovearhead and the inability to structure queries nicely. As I said - firing offense in most teams.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry about that level of reads or writes. It's quite low in absolute terms

Build a table for all cranes: don't encode information into table names.

If you want to remove archive records and if you need to have some in the live table, then after day 8 days via some batch process will do it. If you don't need the archive data in the live table, then move it immediately, Otherwise just use one table and look at [Slowly changing dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) to keep it all in one place